# Windows macros in clang 3.5, ndk r10e, CMake

Tags: c++, android-ndk, macros, cmake, clang++

I am building a CMake-based project for Android, using NDK r10e, x86_64, toolchain name is `arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.5`

Currently I'm getting very strange errors, suggesting that some Windows preprocessor macros come out, like `_WIN32`, `_WIN64`, `__MINGW32__`.

My project uses parts of stlplus3, version 3-03-11, particularly, `filesystem`

I use CMake Android toolchain from https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake (this toolchain is used in OpenCV)

Here is CMake call

```
set ANDROID_SDK=C:\Android\sdk
set ANDROID_NDK=c:\Android\android-ndk-r10e
set ANDROID_EXECUTABLE=%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\android.bat 
set CMAKE_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%CMAKE_PATH%

cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="%~dp0\..\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=%ANDROID_NDK%^
     -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.5 -DANDROID_EXTRA_NDK_VERSIONS="-r10e"^
     -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON"^
     -G"Ninja"
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
[29/186] Building CXX object modules/3rdparty/stlplus3/CMakeFiles/stlplus3.dir/portability_fixes.cpp.o 
FAILED: C:\Android\android-ndk-r10e\toolchains\llvm-3.5\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe   -DANDROID -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS 
-isystem C:/Android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include -isystem C:/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -isystem C:/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -isystem C:/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include/backward 
-IC:/opencv/android-clang/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv -IC:/opencv/android-clang/sdk/native/jni/include -I../modules/common 
-fPIC -fPIE -flax-vector-conversions -Ofast -MMD -MT 
modules/3rdparty/stlplus3/CMakeFiles/stlplus3.dir/portability_fixes.cpp.o -MF 
modules/3rdparty/stlplus3/CMakeFiles/stlplus3.dir/portability_fixes.cpp.o.d -o modules/3rdparty/stlplus3/CMakeFiles/stlplus3.dir/portability_fixes.cpp.o 
-c ../modules/3rdparty/stlplus3/portability_fixes.cpp 
../modules/3rdparty/stlplus3/portability_fixes.cpp:12:10: fatal error: 'windows.h' file not found 
#include "windows.h"
```

Here is the respective code from `portability_fixes.hpp`

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#define MSWINDOWS
#endif
```

Here is the respective code from `portability_fixes.cpp`

```
#include "portability_fixes.hpp"

#ifdef MSWINDOWS
#include "windows.h"
#endif
```

I have also tried adding code like th following

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(ANDROID)
#error win32
#endif

#if defined(_WIN64) && defined(ANDROID)
#error win64
#endif

#if defined(_WIN32_WCE) && defined(ANDROID)
#error win32_wce
#endif
```

And have got two error messages, "win32" and "win64".

I have also tried to work around these macros, adding `... && !defined(ANDROID)`. But then I've got an liker error about undefined symbol `__mingw_aligned_malloc` in file `mm_malloc.h`

Studying its code, I've found the following:

```
static __inline__ void *__attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__,
                                   __malloc__))
_mm_malloc(size_t __size, size_t __align)
    ....
  void *__mallocedMemory;
#if defined(__MINGW32__)
  __mallocedMemory = __mingw_aligned_malloc(__size, __align);
#elif defined(_WIN32)
  __mallocedMemory = _aligned_malloc(__size, __align);
#elif defined(__ANDROID__)
  __mallocedMemory = memalign(__align, __size);
#else
    ....
```

So, it looks like I'm doing something wrong, but don't understand what.

Switching compiler is not an option, because of compatibility issues with other projects.

So how do I make the compiler to undefine these macros?

Also, OpenCV builds fine with the same options.

Update: I've downloaded x86 version of NDK r10e and it has compiled my code fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bugs in 64-bit build of NDK r10e.

I've downloaded x86 version of NDK r10e and it has compiled my code fine.